# Not In like database in AWK

Tags: unix, awk, aix

How to simplify the != statements. I have plenty of values like this

```
if (charNr%2 == 0 && newChar != " " && newChar !="0" && newChar !="1" && newChar !="2" && newChar !="3" && newChar !="4" && newChar !="5" && newChar !="6" && newChar !="7" && newChar !="8" && newChar !="9" ) {newStr  =  newStr newChar   }
```

I want to use it in AWK AIX 7.1.2 fuctions. Please help me.

I am expecting something like

```
 if (charNr%2 == 0 && newChar NOT IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) ) {newStr  =  newStr newChar   }
```

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output as right now we're all guessing at what you need so the solution you end up with might not actually be the best for whatever you're really trying to do. As of right now you can do what you ask for with `newChar !~ /[0-9]/` but that might be completely wrong for your real needs.

Answer (score 4):

The `in` operator in Awk works with array keys, so you can do:

```
keys["foo"];
"foo" in keys # true
```

For your example, you would have to create an array containing all the keys first:

```
keys[1]; keys[2]; keys[3]; # etc.
```

In this specific case you could use a loop to help you:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) keys[i] # set keys from 0 to 9
newChar in keys # true if newChar is 0-9
```

In a general case, you can use:

```
input = "first,second,third,fourth"
n = split(input, temp, /,/)
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) keys[temp[i]]
```

Comment: can also use split function to initialize array.. for ex: `awk 'BEGIN{split("1,2,3",a,/,/); print a[2]}'`

Comment: That example is slightly misleading, because the keys and values match, but in general it won't work because the keys of `a` will always be 1, 2, 3, 4, `split` uses the string to get the values.

Comment: you're right, I missed that.. I was thinking about values only, not keys...

Answer (score 1):

if your black list is single digits there are easier ways, but assuming that you have a list of arbitrary tokens, you can use this trick

```
awk -v n='t1 t2 t3 t4' 'FS n FS !~ FS $1 FS'
```

it adds the FS to the beginning and end of the list and check for pattern match with a FS padded keyword (here `$1`, replace with your variable).  Here assuming the default field delimiter is used, otherwise use the same delimiter in the list of tokens.

For example,

```
$ awk -v n='11 13 17 19' 'FS n FS !~ FS $1 FS' < <(seq 10 20)

10
12
14
15
16
18
20
```

if your list is arbitrary single chars (or digits), you can simplify it to

```
$ awk 'FS $1 FS !~ / [2357] /' < <(seq 10)

1
4
6
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the `!=` is to have the unwanted values in an array and to `(value in array==0)`, like this:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++) a[i]  # add values 0...9 to array a
}
($1 in a==0) {              # if value is not found in array
    print                   # print it
}' <(seq 1 12)              # test values
10
11
12
```